# Can't print a LineEdit value in python

Tags: python, forms, printing, qlineedit

[image]

[image]

```
class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):

def __init__(self):

    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)


def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(410, 325)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setUnderline(False)
    font.setWeight(75)
    Form.setFont(font)
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)     
    spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
    self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
    self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Entrar)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Cadastrar)


    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Gerenciador de Ordem de Serviço"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Faça login ou cadastre-se"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Login:"))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Senha:"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Entrar"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Cadastrar"))


def Entrar(self): #aqui faz a busca dos dados de cadastro, se corretos e cadastrados vai para programa principal
        log = self.lineEdit.text()
        passw = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        logqry = 'SELECT NomeUsu FROM registro WHERE NomeUsu ='  + "\""+ log +"\""
        passqry = 'SELECT SenhaProg FROM registro WHERE SenhaProg =' + "\"" + passw + "\""
        print(self.lineEdit.text())
        print(log)
        print(passw)
        print(logqry)
        print(passqry)
```

Hi, I have this part of my code, is that a gui, and a did a method that it's supposed to print the value of the LineEdit and LineEdit_2 value, but when I run the event the , that don't show nothing, like the lineEdit was empty.

Can anyone help?? Sorry about any gramatical mistake.

Comment: Are you sure `lineEdit_2` isn't empty?

Comment: Yeah, I run the program and them write somethin in both the lineEdits, but when I press the button that prints nothing

Comment: are you actually calling the `Entrar` method anywhere? From this code it seems that you're not.

Comment: I'm calling in this program that I posted in line "self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Entrar)"

Comment: when I press the button the program print both of the sql querys, but the log and passw variable are empty

Comment: And does it print `self.lineEdit.text()`?

Comment: the program print a empty line

Comment: I add two Images with my program running

Answer (score 0):

`log` and `passw` are not ordinary Python strings, they're `QString`s, so to print them you have to convert them to strings first.

```
log = str(self.lineEdit.text())
passw = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
```

Or, If you want them to be `QString`s, print them as follows

```
print("%s\n%s" % log,passw)
```

Comment: That's odd. Where do you expect these strings to be printed?

Comment: the real application is to use this two variables to do a query in sqlite3, I'm justin priting in Python Shell to test why those variables does not appears in my sql query.

Comment: Then I suppose, it has something to do with Python Shell. These shells as well as IDLE often show weird output (or, in your case, don't show _any output at all_). You can try running all this directly from console.

Comment: that's not right, becouse I have another Form that does almost the exactly thing, and that works. The problem is only this form.